# CLOB Commits not working when run back to back

Tags: xml, oracle, clob, xmltype, xmltable

We are running an older Oracle Server, 10.1.0.5.

I have some simple code replaces one CLOB with another in a different column. 
 I am replacing specific strings with another simpler string in a different column, so I can perform some basic XML Parsing. Ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059405/oracle-clob-to-xmltype-errors).

I would expect to do a series of update commands, with commits in between each, and have all of the fields updated properly.  If I run it as follows, only the last query gets committed, despite running as a script.  The intermittent commits don't seem to take.

I can get it to work, by running each update + commit line by line, but I am wondering why I can't run these all at once.  I have only shown the first 2 updates.  What am I missing?

```
set define off

update TABLE1 SET COL_CLEANED = replace(COL_ORIGINAL,'&#xA0;',  ' ');
COMMIT;

update TABLE1 SET COL_CLEANED = replace(COL_ORIGINAL,'&#xA7;',  'SECT.');
COMMIT;

update TABLE1 ...
```

Thank you,

sse

Comment: you are updating the same field, COL_CLEANSED twice, and the 2nd will overwrite the 1st.  Unless you got an error , then I doubt a rollback occured.

Comment: You are right of course, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @OldProgrammer said, you're repeatedly replacing the `COL_CLEANED` value and overwriting earlier changes...

Imagine you started with a simple value that required multiple replacements:

```
create table table1 (col_original clob, col_cleaned clob);

insert into table1 (col_original)
values (to_clob('Test&#xA0;without&#xA0;breaks - &#xA7;1'));
```

and did the first update:

```
update TABLE1 SET COL_CLEANED = replace(COL_ORIGINAL,'&#xA0;',  ' ');

select col_original, col_cleaned from table1;

COL_ORIGINAL                             COL_CLEANED                             
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Test&#xA0;without&#xA0;breaks - &#xA7;1  Test without breaks - &#xA7;1
```

Now you do the second update:

```
update TABLE1 SET COL_CLEANED = replace(COL_ORIGINAL,'&#xA7;',  'SECT.');

select col_original, col_cleaned from table1;

COL_ORIGINAL                             COL_CLEANED                             
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Test&#xA0;without&#xA0;breaks - &#xA7;1  Test&#xA0;without&#xA0;breaks - SECT.1
```

There has been no commit and no rollback. But you took the *original* value - which still had both the old patterns - and replaced the second pattern in that. The first update has simply been overwritten by the second.

You need to apply successive updates to the *cleaned* value; only the first update uses the original value:

```
-- first update is based on COL_ORIGINAL
update TABLE1 SET COL_CLEANED = replace(COL_ORIGINAL,'&#xA0;',  ' ');

select col_original, col_cleaned from table1;

COL_ORIGINAL                             COL_CLEANED                             
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Test&#xA0;without&#xA0;breaks - &#xA7;1  Test without breaks - &#xA7;1           

-- subsequent updates are based on COL_CLEANED to keep earlier changes    
update TABLE1 SET COL_CLEANED = replace(COL_CLEANED,'&#xA7;',  'SECT.');
--------------------------------------------^^^^^^^

select col_original, col_cleaned from table1;

COL_ORIGINAL                             COL_CLEANED                             
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Test&#xA0;without&#xA0;breaks - &#xA7;1  Test without breaks - SECT.1
```

The commits aren't really needed, incidentally; you should commit once per logical transaction, not once per statement.

---

Incidentally, you could use [the `utl_i18n.unescape_reference()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_I18N.html#GUID-721DF8FD-2DBE-4CFD-BCDE-656242BD497E) for this, but in your example it will give you a mutibyte 'section' character rather than the string `'SECT.'`:

```
update TABLE1 SET COL_CLEANED = UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(COL_ORIGINAL);

select col_original, col_cleaned from table1;

COL_ORIGINAL                             COL_CLEANED                             
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Test&#xA0;without&#xA0;breaks - &#xA7;1  Test without breaks - §1
```

and it may make other changes differently to your other hard-coded replacements. On the other hand, at some point your `col_original` has probably been passed through a similar function to [escape](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_I18N.html#GUID-9E385ED0-9D95-416F-BC78-2C8280B38263) references to the values you currently have stored; as the real original text would have had `§` for that to have been escaped to `&#xA7;`, it may be more appropriate to reinstate it to that original character anyway. Unless you're ending up in a character set that can't display it, perhaps.

Comment: spot on.  And thank you for the additional ancillary info regarding UNESCAPE_REFERENCE.  You are right, about the Section Char.  The issue we have is the database is old and using USACII7 encoding, with BYTE Semantics.  Reinstating it isn't an option until we migrate to a modern character set. Thanks again!